# Civi mail - can not use Bold / strong or any h1-6 tags in email?

Tags: civimail

Civi mail - can not use Bold / strong or any h1-6 tags in email ??

This is the error I get. I'm using 4.6.16.

> Sorry, an error occurred and your information was not saved.

Comment: Thanks for your post.  You are more likely to get a helpful answer if you could provide a bit more detail.  What steps did you take?  What did you expect to happen?  Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I would also suggest that you try to do the same thing on the demo site to see if you get the same problem: https://civicrm.org/demo

Comment: Im sending an email via civimail (a test email at the moment )and when i use ckeditor or tinymce on any version of civicrm i get a pop up error "Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved" when turning the text bold. But when use inline style via the source view it sends the email with bold but i can not just use the <strong> some text </strong> or <b> some text</b> in the email template ?